# Interactive console with NetBeans project modules on the classpath

Tags: python, netbeans, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to wrap my head around Python, while my brain works for Java and Scala, so please excuse if this question is ill-formulated.

I have managed to setup NetBeans 6.9 with Python 2.7 on OS X. I can compile and run my project, fine.

Now what I want is something equivalent to sbt's `console` command. I want to **launch the Python REPL with my project on the classpath**, so that basically I can interactively call into my custom functions and classes.

There is `Window` -> `PythonConsole`, but that launches some Python (or Jython?) 2.5 instead, and my modules don't seem to be in the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Go `tools->python platforms` and set the default platform to python 2.7. This should cause `window->pythonConsole` to launch the correct version of python.

As for then being able to import your custom modules... that's the problem I'm currently having too.